# Angular-js filter with some parameters

Tags: angularjs, filter, parameters

I have an array of products that I'm repeating over using ng-repeat and am using

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:company_filter">
```

The filter is working but i want to pass some parameters to my filter like product type, ...

How can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In templates, you can separate filter arguments by colons.

```
{{ yourExpression | yourFilter: arg1:arg2:... }}
```

From Javascript, you call it as

```
$filter('yourFilter')(yourExpression, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple parameters on your custom filter with the following syntax:

```
product in products | myFilter:firstParameter:secondParameter
```

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/9xy3851g/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass an object having multiple fields as a parameter of your filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:params">
$scope.params = { company: "xyz", type: "abc" }
```